# How to omit/set xmlns:xsd attribute from soap parameter?

Tags: node.js, soap

I am using the module **[strong-soap](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap)** with **Node.js** and I am trying to send a request RPC to a web service.

I created a client with options:

```
var wsdlOptions = {
    attributesKey: '$attributes',
    valueKey: '$value'
};
```

And I set the parameters as the following:

```
var args = {
        'para': {
            $attributes: {
                $xsiType: "xsd:string"
            },
            $value: 'a'
        },
        'parb': {
            $attributes: {
                $xsiType: "xsd:string"
            },
            $value: 'b'
        },
        'parc': {
            $attributes: {
                $xsiType: "xsd:string"
            },
            $value: 'c'
        }
    };
```

However, when I call the method, it produces the xml (envelope):

```
    <ns1:query xmlns:ns1="http://<host>">
      <para xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="" xsi:type="xsd:string">a</para>
      <parb xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="" xsi:type="xsd:string">b</parb>
      <parc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="" xsi:type="xsd:string">c</parc>
    </ns1:query>
```

And I get an error message:

**The value of the attribute "prefix="xmlns",localpart="xsd",rawname="xmlns:xsd"" is invalid. Prefixed namespace bindings may not be empty.**

I did not see any way to set or remove this parameter from the method call. 
When I set $xsiType inside the parameter, the lib automatically sets an empty xmlns:xsd.

The web service I am interacting with has an old soap implementation and I think this might be the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When specifying the value for `$xsiType` try using the following format:

```
"{namespace uri}namespace:type"
```

For example for the `xsd` namespace you can specify the following:

```
$xsiType: "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}xsd:string"
```

The above should yield something along the lines of:

```
<para xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xsd:string">a</para>
```